# Add GitHub Team in Org to a REPO

Tags: curl, github, github-api

I'm trying to do a Curl request to add a team to a repo like this:

```
curl --user $USERNAME:$TOKEN -X PUT -d "" "https://api.github.com/teams/<team name>/repos/<org>/$REPONAME"
```

My variables are the correct one, but I keep getting a message not found error. Anyone have an advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct endpoint from [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository) is :

```
PUT /teams/:id/repos/:org/:repo
```

You have to specify the team ID not the team name

The following will get the team ID for the `Developers` team and perform the `PUT` request to add repo to the specified team :

```
username=your_user
password=your_password

org=your_org
repo=your_repo

team=Developers

teamid=$(curl -s --user $username:$password "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/teams" | \
    jq --arg team "$team" '.[] | select(.name==$team) | .id')

curl -v --user $username:$password -d "" -X PUT "https://api.github.com/teams/$teamid/repos/$org/$repo"
```

Note for this example JSON parsing is done with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Also consider to use [Personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) with scope `admin:org` instead of your username/password (then use `-H "Authorization: Token $TOKEN"`)

Comment: Does this request change at all if the team is private? Querying for the team didn't return the team from the org list of teams. I had to get the ID using Dev Tools. So far when I execute the put request I get a 204 error saying No Content.

Comment: I've tested this on a `secret` team (only visible to members) and it worked for me. `204` is the expected code, check the [doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository).

Comment: You can add [page parameter](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) if you have more than 30 teams  
i.e. `https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/teams?page=2`

Comment: Pay attention to the version of Github you are using, as the path is different in newer versions > 2.17, fwiw.  `PUT /teams/:team_id/repos/:owner/:repo` is now `PUT /orgs/:org/teams/:team_slug/repos/:owner/:repo`.

Comment: No need to request all teams and filter them if you know team name
`curl -H "Authorization: token $ACCESS_TOKEN" -s "https://api.github.com/orgs/$ORG_NAME/teams/$team" | jq ".id"`

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is slightly out of date now.

Try here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions

```
put /orgs/{org}/teams/{team_slug}/repos/{owner}/{repo}

curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: token ......." \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/teams/TEAM_SLUG/repos/ORG/REPO \
  -d '{"permission":"permission"}'
```

Comment: When I look at the GitHub UI via "/settings/access" of a repo, it is about assigning teams and users a "role" for a repository that seems to bundle the permissions, but not the permissions themselves. Is there another endpoint for repository role assignment of teams/users?

Comment: Nevermind, mixed up collaborators and the specific team permissions... Still being confused about it, tbh...