# Add member to repo GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm using GitHub Actions to perform CI/CD for my job, and I'm asked to create an action/actions to add members to a repo.

For context, currently I have a team called `test` in an organization called `org`, and I have a repository called `test-proj`. I want to add the team `test` into the repo `test-proj` using GitHub Actions.

I have searched through many websites, but almost none of them mentions anything about adding members, and the ones that do really don't go into details about the code.

I was wondering if this is even possible, and if so, how could I implement it?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What do you mean by "adding the team into the repo"? Giving the team write permissions?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, that's exactly what I want to ask about. If possible, I also want to make the team's permission higher than just write (like edit, admin, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add teams or team members to a particular repo in an organization.

Well, there is no direct action associated with adding a team or team member to an organization. You can try the API (Running a shell command in a GitHub action).You will need the GitHub token for authorization before you can add teams or collaborators to the repo. Personally, I have not tried it. I hope it will work.
[Check this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498035/add-github-team-in-org-to-a-repo)

The Commands will be like this:

To add Collaborators

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repos/$org/$repo_name/collaborators/$username"
```

To add Teams.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/teams/$team_slug/repos/$org/$repo_name"
```

You can create separate jobs for both and trigger them on some kind of event.

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll make sure to check it and accept the answer!

Comment: Is there any special permission/privilege that I need to have in order to run the commands?

Comment: Yes, the user's (Token you are using) should have repo write access, and permission to add Collaborator, Once check the permission assigned to token and then you can try.

Comment: Is that token the same as the one in `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}?`

Comment: Yes! Only one token will be need with all necessary permissions

Comment: The authenticated user has to have [admin permissions on the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/teams/teams?apiVersion=2022-11-28#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions), so `GITHUB_TOKEN` likely won't be sufficient, and you need a personal access token instead. The added team will have default (push) permissions; you can use a payload with a `permission` field to update that, see the API docs linked. And lastly, using the GitHub CLI instead of curl might be a little more convenient.

Comment: Yes, you can go git CLI, But it will increase some complexity, like installation of github cli and authentication. Yes here `GITHUB_TOKEN` represent personal access token (Either classic token or fine grained (recommended))